# Sorting dict - different result using dict.keys() instead of dict.items()

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I am trying to sort a dictionary in python using sorted function, but my_dict.items() give me correct result and my_dict.keys() gives me incorrect

```
my_dict={"one":1, "two":2,"three":3, "four":4,"five":5}

sorted(my_dict.items(), key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)
```

Output:

```
[('five', 5), ('four', 4), ('three', 3), ('two', 2), ('one', 1)]
```

Above is correct, but I need only keys not the corresponding values, so I wrote:

```
sorted(my_dict.keys(), key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)
```

Output:

```
['two', 'four', 'one', 'five', 'three']
```

Above is incorrect result, what I am doing wrong? Please help me with the right solution.

Comment: when you're sorting by the keys only, `x[1]` means the second character in each word - notice that they are indeed in descending order: `w, o, n, i, h`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are throwing away the values too early - you need them for the sort. You can use your first solution and then select the first element in each tuple *after* sorting:

```
[key for key, value in sorted(my_dict.items(), key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)]
```

Comment: thanks, got the issue and the solution, above code sample works fine

Answer (score 1):

In the first sort, you apply the function `lambda x: x[1]` to each element in `my_dict.items()`. `my_dict.items()` gives you (key, value) tuples, so you are sorting by value (integers in your case).

In the second sort, you are applying the function `lambda x: x[1]` to each element in `my_dict.keys()`. `my_dict.keys()` gives you strings, so you are sorting by the second character in each string.

Demo:

```
>>> my_dict = {"one":1, "two":2,"three":3, "four":4,"five":5}
>>> f = lambda x: x[1]
>>> my_dict.items()
dict_items([('one', 1), ('two', 2), ('three', 3), ('four', 4), ('five', 5)])
>>> [f(x) for x in my_dict.items()]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> my_dict.keys()
dict_keys(['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'])
>>> [f(x) for x in my_dict.keys()]
['n', 'w', 'h', 'o', 'i']
```

Comment: thanks, that explanation solved my problem